# Always show full time stamp in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, timestamp

I would like to always show the full timestamp for messages in Thunderbird (eg in the inbox). The default settings only shows the time if the email came in the same day:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know the setting or an addon to turn of the "short" time stamp that only shows the time?

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Change_the_Date_Format

Comment: @Robert thanks, worked perfectly...  feel free to add an answer! (using the Config Editor I had to add the value first)

Comment: @Robert ok, seems my joy was premature. On the email list it works fine but I still get the time-only stamp in the message pane (see screen shot). I didn't find anything for the message pane on the Date display format page...  did I miss anything?